# How to use regex to replace exact phrases with a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

i have the following string.

> *keyName:branding-SLES Relocations:(not relocatable)*keyOpenEnd

I want to repalce the *key with {" and the *keyOpenEnd with ": so i have a result string of

> {"Name:branding-SLES Relocations:(not relocatable)":

So i have

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\b"+"key"+@"\b", "{\"");
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\b\*keyOpenEnd\b", "\":");
```

I have tried various diff combinations but nothing works.

Update: Seems to be a bit of confusion on question.
To clarify; I need to replace exact phrases else it will replace 'Key' in KeyOpenEnd aswell as Key which is not good. I need exact phrase replacement.

Comment: You don't appear to have any delimiter after `*key` either at the beginning or the end (when it is the start of `*keyOpenEnd`). So I don't think you have any choice except to replace the longer (less ambiguous) sequence and then to shorter ambiguous one after. In this particular case, however, I think your second `\b` is a problem - in your first regex, `\bkey\b` isn't going to match `keyName`.

Comment: Why need a delimiter when i know th ephrase is '*key' and *keyOpenEnd'? Can i not just say replace *key with X AND keyOpenEnd with Y in a way that does not replace the key in keyOpenEnd with X??

Comment: Well, you could do it, if you always have them in that sequence -- then you can make it a single regex. Is that the case? You haven't been very clear about that.

Comment: Yes, always in that sequence, if that helps.

Comment: @Fearghal I've updated my answer to include a single compiled regular expression that you can use, but as you can see `string.Replace` is still faster.

Comment: @Fearghal Look at juharr's answer - but can you also clarify if there might be several of these `*key...*keyOpenEnd` sequences within one string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `string.Replace` and make sure you replace the more specific value first

```
output = output.Replace("*keyOpenEnd", "\":").Replace("*key", "{\"");
```

**EDIT**

Here's test code to compare regular expression time versus `string.Replace` and my results

```
string s = "*keyName:branding-SLES Relocations:(not relocatable)*keyOpenEnd";
string desired = "{\"Name:branding-SLES Relocations:(not relocatable)\":";

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var n = Regex.Replace(s, @"\*keyOpenEnd", "\":");
    n = Regex.Replace(n, @"\*key", "{\"");
    Assert.AreEqual(desired, n);
}
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("RegEx Total: {0}", watch.Elapsed);

watch.Reset();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var n = s.Replace("*keyOpenEnd", "\":").Replace("*key", "{\"");
    Assert.AreEqual(desired, n);
}
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("String Replace Total: {0}", watch.Elapsed);
```

Results:

```
RegEx Total: 00:00:00.1742555
String Replace Total: 00:00:00.0385957
```

**Additional Edit**

If you use one regular expression and compile it up front for use, `string.Replace` is still faster

```
string s = "*keyName:branding-SLES Relocations:(not relocatable)*keyOpenEnd";
string desired = "{\"Name:branding-SLES Relocations:(not relocatable)\":";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\*key(.*)\*keyOpenEnd", RegexOptions.Compiled);

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var n = r.Replace(s, "{\"$1\":");
    Assert.AreEqual(desired, n);
}
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("RegEx Total: {0}", watch.Elapsed);

watch.Reset();
watch.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    var n = s.Replace("*keyOpenEnd", "\":").Replace("*key", "{\"");
    Assert.AreEqual(desired, n);
}
watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("String Replace Total: {0}", watch.Elapsed);
```

Result:

```
RegEx Total: 00:00:00.0960996
String Replace Total: 00:00:00.0393491
```

Comment: Not sure what this does. Can you explain?

Comment: See updated question, added clarification and desired example string

Comment: Tried this, does it work byu looking for the specific before the more generic search terms? This seems to be slower than regex but does work. Its awkward however as it really does depend on sequence of replace terms and i have a few.

Comment: @Fearghal If you have more than these two terms to replace you might want to expand on your question.  Also how did you determine that this is slower than two regular expression calls, I would expect this to be faster, but have not actually tested it.

Comment: @Fearghal I just ran a test on the regular expression versus the string replace and string replace was 4 times faster on my machine.  If you want I can put my test code into the answer.

Comment: @juharr - `(.*)` will cause problems if Fearghal's string contains more than one `*key...*keyOpenEnd` set (he hasn't said...), since matches are 'greedy'. If that is the case then `(.*?)` should do the trick (making it a lazy match).

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `^\*key` with { and `\*keyOpenEnd$` with }

Edited, if * is a wild card then do the following

replace `key(.*)keyOpenEnd` with `{"$1"`

Comment: This will still result in *key being replaced in both *key and *keyOpenEnd$ no?

Comment: See updated question, added clarification and desired example string

Comment: @Fearghal so the * actually means some string instead of a '*' character?